# how to specify audio output device for twilio js call in browser

Tags: javascript, macos, audio, webrtc, twilio

I'm trying to use the twilio.js library to have two phone calls happening simultaneously in two separate Google Chrome tabs and stream the audio to/from those calls to another program separately. I think using mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() and setting the audio element to use the desired deviceID may be the way to do this, but I'm not sure what element I would be targeting in this case or how to find it.

I'm using node and OSX.

Comment: What issue are you having streaming the audio to "another program"?

Comment: Have you checked out https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ ?

Comment: @jib i was looking at this but it seems like I need to know the specific page element that i want to change the output device for. i'm not sure what is producing the sound when twilio's library makes a call. do you know how i can find this out?

Comment: @guest271314 i just want to change the audio output device for a specific browser tab. specifically, if i have two pages open with twilio calls, i might want the audio of one to use my computer speakers and the audio of another to be sent through soundflower.

Comment: @chjno Not sure what soundflower is. You can specify a `destination` using `AudioContext`.

Comment: So this question is about finding an element that the twilio library creates for you? I don't know twilio, but that sounds wrong. This is receiver side right? So aren't you in charge of putting the stream from the peer connection to use on the page?

Comment: @jib I'm not sure but here's the example code that I went off of if you feel like taking a look: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-node/tree/master/public.